# MATLAB nntraintool not working

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I want to train my recognition system with the feature dataset that I have created.

There are 9 inputs (features) and 40 targets (classes)

inputs and targets are on the same matrix. The first 9 columns are the features and the remaining 40 columns are the outputs

I have written this code below:

```
load dataSet.mat;

inputs = featureSet(:,1:9)';

targets = featureSet(:,10:49)';

% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = ns;

net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = trRa/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = vaRa/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = teRa/100;



% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs);

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs);
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs);
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs);
```

I have copied this code from my previous working character recognition application. There is only two differences from the former application: input count and target count.

After starting training GUI window of nntraintool opens and no action is observed. Additionally, I get message at the bottom says "Performance goal met."

What could be the reason?

[image]